# Aggregating items in aws athena sql

Tags: sql, arrays, aggregate, amazon-athena

Given a database that looks like:

| item | vietnamese | cost | unique_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| fruits | trai cay | 10 | abc123 |
| fruits | trai cay | 8 | foo99 |
| fruits | trai cay | 9 | foo99 |
| fruits | trai cay | 12 | abc123 |
| fruits | trai cay | 14 | abc123 |
| vege | rau | 3 | rr1239 |
| vege | rau | 3 | rr1239 |

When querying through AWS Athena as such:

```
SELECT item, 
    sum(cost) as sum_cost, 
    avg(cost) as avg_cost, 
    array_agg(vietnamese) as vietnamese,
    array_agg(cost) as costs,
    array_agg(unique_id) as unique_ids
FROM foodtable
GROUP BY item
ORDER BY avg_cost
```

I'll get an array of repeated vietnamese translation:

| item | vietnamese |
| --- | --- |
| fruits | [trai cay, trai cay, trai cay, trai cay, trai cay] |

**Is there a way to just keep the last/first value from the `vietnamese` column?**

Also, with the query above, the `unique_ids` value would look like:

| item | unique_ids |
| --- | --- |
| fruits | [abc123, foo99, foo99, abc123, abc123] |

**Is there a way to aggregate the counts** and keep a counter column to achieve?

| item | unique_ids |
| --- | --- |
| fruits | [abc123:3, foo99:2] |

Currently, I've tried just reading the outputs after I get the results from the SQL query by unique-ing with `set(vietnamese)` and `collections.Counter(unique_ids)`. But if it's possible to do that in the SQL query, that'll more desirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Athena has a many functions that operate on arrays, such as [`filter`](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.217/functions/array.html#filter), [`element_at`](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.217/functions/array.html#element_at), [`cardinality`](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.217/functions/array.html#cardinality), [`reduce`](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.217/functions/array.html#reduce), as well as [functions that create and process maps](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.217/functions/map.html). You can use these to process the aggregated arrays.

For example, to count the number of occurrences of each unique ID you can do something like this:

```
SELECT
  item,
  transform_values(multimap_agg(unique_id, 1), (k, v) -> cardinality(v))
GROUP BY item
```

Comment: All of these links are dead.